# jconsole cpu usage vs prometheus cpu usage

Tags: prometheus, grafana, jconsole, jmx-exporter

I have been using prometheus for a couple of days and to get started I decided that replicating the jconsole view of a tiny java application in grafana could be a good start.
Somehow the CPU usage in jconsole and in grafana don't look the same at all.
I use the jmx exporter to export jvm metrics. https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

I am using `irate(process_cpu_seconds_total[1m]) * 100` in Grafana.
I have only one process, so I don't need any filtering.
I was wondering whether the query is wrong or jconsole is doing something else that cannot be done using `process_cpu_seconds_total`.

Best regards

Comment: Try substituting `irate` with `rate` in the query, since `irate` may return unexpected results. See https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832 . Try also increasing the duration in square brackets if Prometheus has `scrape_interval` bigger than 15 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @valyala. the `scrape_interval` is 5s. `irate` still doesn't give the same result as the jconsole.